# Why are my inner tabs not displaying inside my accordion?

Tags: asp.net, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion, jquery-tabs

I'm trying to add some tabs within an accordion like so:

```
        <div id="accordion">
            <h3>Puddy Tat</h3>
            <div>CONTENT FOR Puddy Tat</div>
            <h3>ThoseCats</h3>
            <div id="thoseCats">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#0">Rory</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#1">Gerry</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#2">Lou</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#3">Rod</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="0">Content panel linked to Rory tab, shown by defalt</div>
                <div id="1">Content panel linked to Gerry tab</div>
                <div id="2">Content panel linked to Lou tab</div>
                <div id="3">Content panel linked to Rod tab</div>
            </div>
            <h3>Jackson Browne</h3>
            <div>CONTENT FOR Jackson Browne</div>
            <h3>Bruce Springsteen</h3>
            <div>CONTENT FOR Bruce Springsteen</div>
            <h3>Me First and the Gimme Gimmes</h3>
            <div>CONTENT FOR Me First and the Gimme Gimmes</div>
            <h3>Dwight Yoakam</h3>
            <div>CONTENT FOR Dwight Yoakam</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion({
            collapsible: true
        });
        $("thoseCats").tabs();
    });
</script>
```

...but they are not showing up. I'm using tabs successfully in another website (www.bigsurgarrapata.com). I compared my "head" contents in _SiteLayout.cshtml, and they are exactly the same (as far as css and js used) except for one thing: In my current site (not bigsurgarrapata), I'm using the bootstrap css:

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Just to be sure this wasn't gumming up the works, I commented it out, but still no go - no diff.

Why would the tabs be recalcitrant or coy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umm...perhaps this won't solve your problem but you miss the `#` hash for the ID selector.

So

```
$("thoseCats").tabs();
```

becomes

```
$("#thoseCats").tabs();
```

In my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/8huGc/) it works fine.

Comment: Yep, another rookie mistake by me. That darn cat (me)!